# How to check if an audio device is an aggregate

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

Just a short question i struggle with:
Is there a way to check if the AudioDeviceID i have is an aggregate device?
I'm not sure how i would check this because i didn't found a corresponding selector which i could use with AudioObjectGetPropertyDataSize.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have come up with a solution myself:
Get a list of subdevices by getting the property `kAudioAggregateDevicePropertyActiveSubDeviceList`

If there are no subdevices it will set `OSStatus` to something other than `noErr`. If this is the case you can assume that you have an aggregate device on your hands.

Comment: Which function do use to get the list of sub devices using the above property? Any code snippets ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option I came across while searching the Coreaudio-api mailing list archives (there are some very useful things in there, though it can take a bit of searching).

Aggregate devices have a distinct class ID of `kAudioAggregateDeviceClassID`, so checking that would be a bit more direct.

This snippet that seems to do the trick:

```
                AudioObjectPropertyAddress classAddress = {
                    kAudioObjectPropertyClass,
                    kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
                    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
                };

                AudioClassID classId;
                size = sizeof(AudioClassID);
                err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(ioDeviceId, &classAddress, 0, NULL, &size, &classId);
```

For an aggregate device, `classId` will be `kAudioAggregateDeviceClassID` (`'aagg'`), rather than `kAudioDeviceClassID` or one of the other class IDs.

Original source:
https://lists.apple.com/archives/Coreaudio-api//2009/Oct/msg00182.html

Answer (score 1):

@Hobotrons answer gives you the devices bound to an aggregated device, **not** the aggregated device itself which leads to extra work to find SubDeviceLists of devices that do not have such.

**You get deviceID's of Aggregated Devices same as you already do for all other normal devices**, just that aggregated devices have sub-devices and as such need a special AudioDeviceTransportType which can be used to differentiate them. So try to look out for `kAudioDeviceTransportTypeAggregate`

```cpp
static bool isAggregateDevice(AudioDeviceID deviceID)
{
    AudioDevicePropertyID deviceType = getDeviceTransportType(deviceID);
    return deviceType == kAudioDeviceTransportTypeAggregate;
}

static AudioDevicePropertyID getDeviceTransportType(AudioDeviceID deviceID)
{
    AudioDevicePropertyID deviceTransportType = 0;
    UInt32 propSize = sizeof(AudioDevicePropertyID);
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress propAddress = addressForPropertySelector(kAudioDevicePropertyTransportType);
    AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &propAddress, 0, nil, &propSize, &deviceTransportType);
    return deviceTransportType;
}

AudioObjectPropertyAddress addressForPropertySelector(AudioObjectPropertySelector selector)
{
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress address;
    address.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
    address.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
    address.mSelector = selector;
    return address;
}
```

from here most goes same same es with normal devices.

`isAggregateDevice()`  lets you build logic that allows you to step in a sub routine before asking for any devices inputs or outputs. Trying to ask for inputs or outputs of aggregated devices can crash your application, because they also can have ZERO inputs and ZERO outputs. So to speak aggregated devices also don't like to be asked for inputs or outputs the normal way, when you assume that each device must have also one input or output, which is not the case and the result of the property fetch are misleading when returning 0.
(users or other code can change aggregated devices at any time).

So make sure you know if your deviceID expresses an ID of an aggregated device and after that step into asking for In & Out **OR** SubDeviceList and their In & Out of each bound device..

```
if (isAggregateDevice(deviceID)==true) 
{ 
    /* here ask for SubDeviceList */ 
    /* and maybe after that, climb into each */
    /* aggregated devices for its in's & outs */
} else {
    /* here ask for in's & outs of your normal device */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift Version of Ol Sen's answer:

```swift
    func isVirtualDevice(deviceID: AudioDeviceID) -> Bool {
        let deviceType = getDeviceTransportType(deviceID)
        return UInt32(deviceType) == kAudioDeviceTransportTypeAggregate
    }


    func getDeviceTransportType(_ deviceID: AudioDeviceID) -> AudioDevicePropertyID {
        var deviceTransportType: AudioDevicePropertyID = 0
        var propSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioDevicePropertyID>.size)
        var propAddress = addressForPropertySelector(kAudioDevicePropertyTransportType)
        AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &propAddress, 0, nil, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(mutating: &propSize), &deviceTransportType)
        return deviceTransportType
    }


    func addressForPropertySelector(_ selector: AudioObjectPropertySelector) -> AudioObjectPropertyAddress {
        var address: AudioObjectPropertyAddress = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(
            mSelector: selector,
            mScope: kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
            mElement: AudioObjectPropertyElement(kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster))
        return address
    }
```